# how to set absolute position to top view, not parent in react native

Tags: react-native, position, absolute

I want to a view positioned absolutely to root view.
For example, if there are 3 views, `GrandFatherView`, `FatherView`, `ChildView`.
I want `ChildView` to be positioned absolutely to `GrandFatherView` without changing `FatherView` style.

```
<View> // GrandFatherView
  <View style={{marginTop: 100}}> // FatherView
    <View style={{position:'absolute', left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, height: 10}}> // ChildView
      {{ some contents}}
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

So I want `ChildView` to be at top, but it shows in top 100 as it's inside `FatherView`
I don't want to change FatherView position for this.

Is this impossible without changing hierarchy? Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we have a margin with the value of `x` which in your example 100, then set `-x` for `top` value .

like this:

```
<View> // GrandFatherView
  <View style={{marginTop: 100}}> // FatherView
    <View style={{position:'absolute', left: 0, top: -100, right: 0, height: 10}}> // ChildView
      {{ some contents}}
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make FatherView Fragment instead of a View. as for the rest, you want to know precisely the exact Views sizes, padding, or margins to position your ChildView. Set top value of ChildView to 100 from the FatherView's margin

```
<View> // GrandFatherView
  <> // FatherView
   <View style={{position:'absolute', left: 0, top: 100, right: 0, height: 10}}> // ChildView
     {{ some contents}}
   </View>
  </>
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

<View style={{position:'relative'}}/> // GrandFatherView